# What's the best way to mark "featured" posts in Jekyll?

Tags: design-patterns, jekyll

I'd like to have a set of featured posts on my home page and at the top of my blog -- how should this be done? I think I could add a `featured = true` item to my yaml front matter on each featured post, but this would require me to dig through my posts and manually update each one.

Would it be easier to link to them directly with the `post_url` method? This would require me to either duplicate this code for the two pages or write another `_include` file.

Is there a standard way of handling this type of pattern?

---

Note: At the moment, I'm using a tag like this to get a post variable.

```
{% assign featurepost = site.posts | where:"title","Post Title" %}
```

This seems super clunky. I assume there's a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that adding featured=true is the right way to go, regardless of the extra work.